# How to calculate totals in a grid with the summary function

Tags: extjs

I have a grid with two summary positions. I have a summary at the end of the grid. This is working great. But what I want is to calculate the total price per row. I have 4 columns called 'Aantal, Stukprijs,korting and Totaal'. What I need is that in the 'Totaal' column this sum: (Aantal X Stukprijs) - %korting(means discount).

This is the code for that grid:

```
  xtype: 'gridpanel',
                                id: 'materiaalGrid',
                                autoScroll: true,
                                forceFit: true,
                                store: 'MyArrayStore8',
                                columns: [
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'rownumberer'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                        dataIndex: 'naam',
                                        text: 'Naam',
                                        editor: {
                                            xtype: 'combobox'
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                        dataIndex: 'type',
                                        text: 'Type'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                                        summaryType: 'sum',
                                        dataIndex: 'gewicht',
                                        text: 'Gewicht'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                                        summaryType: 'sum',
                                        dataIndex: 'aantal',
                                        text: 'Aantal',
                                        editor: {
                                            xtype: 'numberfield'
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                                        dataIndex: 'stuks',
                                        text: 'Stukprijs'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                                        dataIndex: 'korting',
                                        text: 'Korting',
                                        editor: {
                                            xtype: 'numberfield',
                                            maxValue: 100
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                                        summaryType: 'sum',
                                        dataIndex: 'stuks',
                                        text: 'Totaal'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'booleancolumn',
                                        dataIndex: 'verkoop',
                                        text: 'Verkoop'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                                        maxWidth: 50,
                                        minWidth: 50,
                                        width: 50,
                                        defaultWidth: 50,
                                        emptyCellText: 'Delete',
                                        menuDisabled: true,
                                        items: [
                                            {
                                                handler: function(view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record, row) {
                                                    var selection = me.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
                                                    if (selection) {
                                                        store.remove(selection);
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                altText: 'Delete'
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                viewConfig: {
                                    enableTextSelection: false
                                },
                                features: [
                                    {
                                        ftype: 'summary'
                                    }
                                ],
                                plugins: [
                                    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {

                                    })
                                ],
```

I can only get the sum of aantal and gewicht in the bottom row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this specific scenario you can try doing this:

- For the result of "Aantal X Stukprijs" AKA *Quantity X Unit price*  (thanks God Google translator exists!) you can create a calculated field implementing the **convert** function on the field declaration, as follows:

> ```
> {
>         name: 'total',
>         type: 'number',
>         convert: function(value, record) {
>             if(!value) {
>                 // Only calculate the value if no value set since the
>                 // Calculated total column will fill this field with a real
>                 // value we don't want to mess
>                 value = record.get('price') * record.get('units');
>             }            
>             return value;
>         }
>     }
> ```

- This will still leave inconsistencies when changing the record value using the  inline editor you will need to add an extra handler for that like this:

> ```
>     grid.on('edit', function(editor, e) {
>            // commit the changes right after editing finished    
>            e.record.set('total'); // force total re-calculation
>            e.record.commit(); 
>    });
> ```

You con see a [**complete example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/overlordhammer/UHBFC/), hope it helps.

Comment: the convert part works perfect! For the grid.on part. I can't get it working. i tried architect too but it seems i put it at the wrong spot

Comment: You can try to add the listener inside the grid declaration like in this [modified version](http://jsfiddle.net/overlordhammer/7vwAB/1/) of the previous example